# Pass a function's return value to another function php 7

Tags: php, function, php-7

I am using php 7, and call plsql procedure and pass a post parameter to it. The code below passes 0 to the procedure.

```
@oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":py", trim($_POST["py"]), -1);
```

But when I change the code like below, it passes post parameter's value.

```
$trimmed = trim($_POST["py"]);
@oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":py", $trimmed, -1);
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: definitely the post value was 0 then changed in the test case of 2nd code

Comment: I have used `var_dump` before calling procedure and it isn't 0.

Comment: You should not use `@` to sweep errors under the rug. If you didn't use it you would have seen the issue.

Comment: It is not error, it just passes zero, function accepts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [docs](http://php.net/oci_bind_by_name) :

```
bool oci_bind_by_name ( resource $statement , string $bv_name , mixed &$variable [, int $maxlength = -1 [, int $type = SQLT_CHR ]] )
//                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as you can see `oci_bind_by_name` expects that the third parameter be passed as a reference , while in your first case you are passing it by value

Comment: @Hikmat https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=oci8 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71148 i think those links would help